# How to update remote origin to use access token instead of SSH key?

Tags: git, github

I forgot my secret passphrase so I created a new GitHub access token in order to pull from / push to my remote repo.
I set the new remote url but then get a `pullfatal` error when I try to do anything with it.

Do you have tips on how to update the remote so that I can access it using my newly created access token?

```
name-mbp:project name$ git remote set-url  origin https://<username>:<access token>@github/<username>/<project-name>.git
name-mbp:project name$ git pullfatal: unable to access 'https://github/<username>/<project-name>/': Could not resolve host: github
```

Comment: Have you tried writing `github.com` instead of `github`?

Comment: And don't put the PAT in the url, it's a security breach waiting to happen. Install the Git Vredential Manager instead.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned:

- install the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) for your platform (Mac/Linux/Windows: see "[Download and Install](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager#download-and-install)")
- Make sure after the installation process that `git config credential.helper` returns `manager`
- Cache your credentials:

  ```
  printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=<me>\npassword=<token> | \
  git credential-manager store
  ```
- Finally, set your URL without credentials in it

  ```
  cd /path/to/local/repo
  git remote set-url origin https://github.com/<me>/<myrepo>
  ```